# Compile-time constexpr cons lists like lisp in C++

Tags: c++

I want to have a linked list like `lisp` cons lists. I want to do this on compile time in C++, utilizing templates and `constexpr` as much as I can. Here is my attempt, I think you'll see immediately what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace chops {
template <typename E1, typename E2>
struct pair {

    constexpr pair()
    : _car{}, _cdr{}
    {}

    constexpr pair(const E1 &car)
    :_car{car}, _cdr{}
    {}

    constexpr pair(const E1 &car, const E2 &cdr)
    :_car{car}, _cdr{cdr}
    {}

    constexpr auto car() const{
        return _car;
    }

    constexpr auto cdr() const{
        return _cdr;
    }

    const E1 _car;
    const E2 _cdr;
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                         pair<E1, E2> p){
    str << p.car() << " " << p.cdr();
    str << "\n";
    return str;
}

template <typename Head, typename Tail>
class list{
    public:
    constexpr list():p{}
    {}

    constexpr list(Head h)
    :p{h}
    {}

    constexpr list(Head h, Tail t)
    :p{h, t}
    {}

    constexpr auto append(Head h) const{
        return list<Head, decltype(p)>{h, p};
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                                    list<Head, Tail> l){
        str << l.p;
        return str;
    }

    private:
    pair<Head, Tail> p;
};
}



int main()
{
    //constexpr const chops::pair p1{3, 4};
    //constexpr const chops::pair<int, decltype(p1)> p2{2, p1};
    //constexpr const chops::pair<int, decltype(p2)> p3(1, p2);

    constexpr chops::list<int, int> l1{6, 5};
    auto l2 = l1.append(4); 
    auto l3 = l2.append(3); 
    auto l4 = l3.append(2); 
    auto l5 = l4.append(1); 
    std::cout << l5;
}
```

You can see that my `list` is just a wrapper around pair actually and I am losing the type safety. `l1` has type `list<int, int>` and others are just nested pairs. This is not good, I want all of them to have the type `list<T>`. How can I handle the type `Tail` without getting it into template parameter of `list` class. Things should stay constexpr, of course.

Comment: Could you change the template of `list` to `template <typename T>` and changes all usages of `Head` and `Tail` to be `T` and `list<T>`, respectively?  EDIT: Actually that probably won't work since the type stored in `p` will need to be a complete type.

Comment: I think I tried it and `append` doesn't work in this case because `append` should work with a `Head` and a `list<Head>`, not `Head` again. But you can try the code yourself.

Comment: Is there a way to redefine a type everytime I call `append`, I wonder? I mean creating a new typedef-like thing. Probably that would not work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a copy ctor:

```
constexpr list(list const& l):p{l.p}
{}
```

then:

```
template<class NewHead>
constexpr auto prepend(NewHead h) const{
    return list<NewHead, list>{h, *this};
}
```

(I renamed the function; it pushes in front, not at the tail).

To append you need some pattern matching.  It is best done as a free function.

```
template<class Head, class Tail>
constexpr auto append( Head h, Tail t ) {
  return list<Head, Tail>(h, t);
}
```

and within `list`:

```
template<class NewTail>
friend constexpr auto append( list h, NewTail t ) {
  return append( car(h.p), append( cdr(h.p), t ) );
}
```

that might work if I got the overloading right.

Use would look like:

```
auto l2 = append(l1,4);
```

Comment: Do you think, after `append`, `l1` and `l2` will have the same type? I am looking at it right now but confused.

Comment: By the way, I don't need `append`, `prepend` is ok. I will only insert from the beginning and try to use structural sharing. This will, hopefully, turn into a functional data structure. I just love starting `constexpr`.

Comment: @meguli No, the type contains the list structure, and the lists have different structure?  One is a `list<int,int>` the other a `list<int, list<int,int>>`.

Comment: Can I make them all have type `list<T>` while being full `constexpr`? I already have this structured type.

Comment: @meguli No; the length has to be part of the type.  On C++ the size of a type is known, and there is no dynamic allocation in constexpr time.  There may be strange hacks you could pull off involving static tagged data and constructors I suppose, but that is pushing it.